# How to use pre-commit hook(Windows batch file) for a particular folder in SVN?

Tags: svn, hook, pre-commit

I want to create a pre-commit hook in SVN (i.e. .bat file for Windows) that checks for empty log messages. Moreover, I want to target this check only for a particular folder in SVN.

Can anybody help regarding the same?

Regards,
Ruhee Jaiswal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Pre-commit hook for comment length Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869248/windows-pre-commit-hook-for-comment-length-subversion)

Comment: @NikolaSmiljanić: don't think this is a duplicate, because OP wants to execute the hook (i.e. do checking for empty comments) only for particular folders...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org), you could enter a [client-side hook](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) there.

TortoiseSVN passes the following parameters to the pre-commit hook:

> PATH DEPTH MESSAGEFILE CWD

where the interesting one is `PATH`:

> PATH
>   A path to a temporary file which contains all the paths for which the operation was started. Each path is on a separate line in the temp file.

So, when your hook is called (could be in any language btw), do the following steps:

1. check the content of `MESSAGEFILE`. If there's a comment inside, everything is fine, return successful from the script (I don't remember whether success is indicated by 0 or !0, just give it a try)
2. if the `MESSAGEFILE` is empty, browse through the file `PATH` and see if there are affected elements in that. If so, return an error; otherwise return success.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a svn property for this if you're on Windows and using TortoiseSVN.

> tsvn:logminsize sets the minimum length of a log message for a commit.
>   If you enter a shorter message than specified here, the commit is
>   disabled. This feature is very useful for reminding you to supply a
>   proper descriptive message for every commit. If this property is not
>   set, or the value is zero, empty log messages are allowed.

Also make sure to check out the [other features](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) like bug tracker integration.

If you'd really like to do this on the server side using a hook you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869248/windows-pre-commit-hook-for-comment-length-subversion), in which case your question is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have hooks, which works on event only for some subtree
2. Hooks are handlers for repository-wide events
3. If you want check only for some parts of affected repo, you **must** add logic inside hook-code

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this answer [Windows Pre-commit hook for comment length Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869248/windows-pre-commit-hook-for-comment-length-subversion) you can use `svnlook dir-changed` to check for specific directories of the current commit.

So you could add something like

```
svnlook dir-changed %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr your_path > nul
 if %errorlevel% equ 0 exit 0

svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > nul  
 if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else exit 0
```