# Code sniffer SVN pre commit hook

Tags: php, svn, pear, pre-commit-hook, phpcodesniffer

I have been trying to get code sniffer to act as a svn pre-commit hook following the guide from pear. However while i am 100% certain my code should be invalid i get no errors and the project commits without problem.

Is there something else that needs to be done besides following the guide given by pear?

[Link to pear guide on code sniffer as pre-commit hook](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.svn-pre-commit.php)

My phpcs-svn-pre-commit file :

```
#!C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe
<?php
/**
 * A commit hook for SVN.
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * @category  PHP
 * @package   PHP_CodeSniffer
 * @author    Jack Bates <ms419@freezone.co.uk>
 * @author    Greg Sherwood <gsherwood@squiz.net>
 * @copyright 2006-2011 Squiz Pty Ltd (ABN 77 084 670 600)
 * @license   http://matrix.squiz.net/developer/tools/php_cs/licence BSD Licence
 * @link      http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer
 */

if (is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php') === true) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
}

define('PHP_CODESNIFFER_SVNLOOK', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook');


/**
 * A class to process command line options.
 *
 * @category  PHP
 * @package   PHP_CodeSniffer
 * @author    Jack Bates <ms419@freezone.co.uk>
 * @author    Greg Sherwood <gsherwood@squiz.net>
 * @copyright 2006-2011 Squiz Pty Ltd (ABN 77 084 670 600)
 * @license   http://matrix.squiz.net/developer/tools/php_cs/licence BSD Licence
 * @version   Release: 1.3.6
 * @link      http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer
 */
class PHP_CodeSniffer_SVN_Hook extends PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI
{


    /**
     * Get a list of default values for all possible command line arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefaults()
    {
        $defaults = parent::getDefaults();

        $defaults['svnArgs'] = array();
        return $defaults;

    }//end getDefaults()


    /**
     * Processes an unknown command line argument.
     *
     * All unknown args are sent to SVN commands.
     *
     * @param string $arg    The command line argument.
     * @param int    $pos    The position of the argument on the command line.
     * @param array  $values An array of values determined from CLI args.
     *
     * @return array The updated CLI values.
     * @see getCommandLineValues()
     */
    public function processUnknownArgument($arg, $pos, $values)
    {
        $values['svnArgs'][] = escapeshellarg($arg);
        return $values;

    }//end processUnknownArgument()


    /**
     * Runs PHP_CodeSniffer over files are directories.
     *
     * @param array $values An array of values determined from CLI args.
     *
     * @return int The number of error and warning messages shown.
     * @see getCommandLineValues()
     */
    public function process($values=array())
    {
        if (empty($values) === true) {
            $values = parent::getCommandLineValues();
        }

        // Get list of files in this transaction.
        $command = PHP_CODESNIFFER_SVNLOOK.' changed '.implode(' ', $values['svnArgs']);
        $handle  = popen($command, 'r');
        if ($handle === false) {
            echo 'ERROR: Could not execute "'.$command.'"'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
            exit(2);
        }

        $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
        fclose($handle);

        // Do not check deleted paths.
        $contents = preg_replace('/^D.*/m', null, $contents);

        // Drop the four characters representing the action which precede the path on
        // each line.
        $contents = preg_replace('/^.{4}/m', null, $contents);

        $values['standard'] = $this->validateStandard($values['standard']);
        if (PHP_CodeSniffer::isInstalledStandard($values['standard']) === false) {
            // They didn't select a valid coding standard, so help them
            // out by letting them know which standards are installed.
            echo 'ERROR: the "'.$values['standard'].'" coding standard is not installed. ';
            $this->printInstalledStandards();
            exit(2);
        }

        $phpcs = new PHP_CodeSniffer(
            $values['verbosity'],
            $values['tabWidth'],
            $values['encoding']
        );

        // Set file extensions if they were specified. Otherwise,
        // let PHP_CodeSniffer decide on the defaults.
        if (empty($values['extensions']) === false) {
            $phpcs->setAllowedFileExtensions($values['extensions']);
        }

        // Set ignore patterns if they were specified.
        if (empty($values['ignored']) === false) {
            $phpcs->setIgnorePatterns($values['ignored']);
        }

        // Set some convenience member vars.
        if ($values['errorSeverity'] === null) {
            $this->errorSeverity = PHPCS_DEFAULT_ERROR_SEV;
        } else {
            $this->errorSeverity = $values['errorSeverity'];
        }

        if ($values['warningSeverity'] === null) {
            $this->warningSeverity = PHPCS_DEFAULT_WARN_SEV;
        } else {
            $this->warningSeverity = $values['warningSeverity'];
        }

        // Initialize PHP_CodeSniffer listeners but don't process any files.
        $phpcs->setCli($this);
        $phpcs->process(array(), $values['standard'], $values['sniffs']);

        // Need double quotes around the following regex beause the vertical whitespace
        // char is not always treated correctly for whatever reason.
        foreach (preg_split("/\v|\n/", $contents, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $path) {
            // No need to process folders as each changed file is checked.
            if (substr($path, -1) === '/') {
                continue;
            }

            // We need to check ignore rules ourself because they are
            // not checked when processing a single file.
            if ($phpcs->shouldProcessFile($path) === false) {
                continue;
            }

            // Get the contents of each file, as it would be after this transaction.
            $command = PHP_CODESNIFFER_SVNLOOK.' cat '.implode(' ', $values['svnArgs']).' '.escapeshellarg($path);
            $handle  = popen($command, 'r');
            if ($handle === false) {
                echo 'ERROR: Could not execute "'.$command.'"'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
                exit(2);
            }

            $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
            fclose($handle);

            $phpcs->processFile($path, $contents);
        }//end foreach

        return $this->printErrorReport(
            $phpcs,
            $values['reports'],
            $values['showSources'],
            $values['reportFile'],
            $values['reportWidth']
        );

    }//end process()


    /**
     * Prints out the usage information for this script.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function printUsage()
    {
        parent::printUsage();

        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo '    Each additional argument is passed to the `svnlook changed ...`'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '    and `svnlook cat ...` commands.  The report is printed on standard output,'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '    however Subversion displays only standard error to the user, so in a'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '    pre-commit hook, this script should be invoked as follows:'.PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo '    '.basename($_SERVER['argv'][0]).' ... "$REPOS" -t "$TXN" >&2 || exit 1'.PHP_EOL;

    }//end printUsage()


}//end class

$phpcs = new PHP_CodeSniffer_SVN_Hook();
$phpcs->checkRequirements();

$numErrors = $phpcs->process();
if ($numErrors !== 0) {
    exit(1);
}

?>
```

And my pre-commit file from subversion:

```
#!/bin/sh

# PRE-COMMIT HOOK
#
# The pre-commit hook is invoked before a Subversion txn is
# committed.  Subversion runs this hook by invoking a program
# (script, executable, binary, etc.) named 'pre-commit' (for which
# this file is a template), with the following ordered arguments:
#
#   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
#   [2] TXN-NAME     (the name of the txn about to be committed)
#
#   [STDIN] LOCK-TOKENS ** the lock tokens are passed via STDIN.
#
#   If STDIN contains the line "LOCK-TOKENS:\n" (the "\n" denotes a
#   single newline), the lines following it are the lock tokens for
#   this commit.  The end of the list is marked by a line containing
#   only a newline character.
#
#   Each lock token line consists of a URI-escaped path, followed
#   by the separator character '|', followed by the lock token string,
#   followed by a newline.
#
# The default working directory for the invocation is undefined, so
# the program should set one explicitly if it cares.
#
# If the hook program exits with success, the txn is committed; but
# if it exits with failure (non-zero), the txn is aborted, no commit
# takes place, and STDERR is returned to the client.   The hook
# program can use the 'svnlook' utility to help it examine the txn.
#
# On a Unix system, the normal procedure is to have 'pre-commit'
# invoke other programs to do the real work, though it may do the
# work itself too.
#
#   ***  NOTE: THE HOOK PROGRAM MUST NOT MODIFY THE TXN, EXCEPT  ***
#   ***  FOR REVISION PROPERTIES (like svn:log or svn:author).   ***
#
#   This is why we recommend using the read-only 'svnlook' utility.
#   In the future, Subversion may enforce the rule that pre-commit
#   hooks should not modify the versioned data in txns, or else come
#   up with a mechanism to make it safe to do so (by informing the
#   committing client of the changes).  However, right now neither
#   mechanism is implemented, so hook writers just have to be careful.
#
# Note that 'pre-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will
# invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must
# have filesystem-level permission to access the repository.
#
# On a Windows system, you should name the hook program
# 'pre-commit.bat' or 'pre-commit.exe',
# but the basic idea is the same.
#
# The hook program typically does not inherit the environment of
# its parent process.  For example, a common problem is for the
# PATH environment variable to not be set to its usual value, so
# that subprograms fail to launch unless invoked via absolute path.
# If you're having unexpected problems with a hook program, the
# culprit may be unusual (or missing) environment variables.
# 
# Here is an example hook script, for a Unix /bin/sh interpreter.
# For more examples and pre-written hooks, see those in
# the Subversion repository at
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/ and
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/


REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
   grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1

# Check that the author of this commit has the rights to perform
# the commit on the files and directories being modified.
commit-access-control.pl "$REPOS" "$TXN" commit-access-control.cfg || exit 1

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\scripts\phpcs-svn-pre-commit "$REPOS" -t "$TXN" >&2 || exit 1

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

I am pretty new to both SVN and codesniffer so i am pretty much just following guides and running tests as i go along. Any advice or tips on getting this to work will be appreciated :)

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get some results out of my svn hook, it now however shows a list of errors based on the script. I am not familiar with the scripting language required for SVN so i have no clue how to solve these.

List of errors:

REPOS is not recognized as internal or external command

TXN is not recognized as internal or external command

unknown command '/usr/local/bin/svnlook'

$SVNLOOK is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: It looks to me you have edited the wrong file. Re-read the docs in there, you skipped the part on what you have to edit / do on a windows system. It looks like you are using a windows system, right?

Comment: I am indeed using a windows system, windows 7 to be precise however i can't really find anything mentioning windows on the guide i linked above. Also i don't see how there are any other files, there is only one phpcs-svn-pre-commit file wich is located at C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\scripts\ . Same with mypre commit file wich is located at C:\repositories\test\hooks\ wich is my test repository.

Comment: For troubleshooting, create yourself a pre-commit hook that outputs some message to STDERR (2) and always returns an exist code larger than 0.  This will prevent all commits. When you get that to work (no commits possible any longer) you can wiggle with the concrete codesniffer one.

Comment: See here for some related **windows** example (you see they are talking about `.bat` files?) [Windows Pre-commit hook for comment length Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869248/windows-pre-commit-hook-for-comment-length-subversion) - it always is a good boilerplate for a simple pre-commit hook windows shell executeable batch file.

Comment: I looked at the question you pointed out and managed to get the script they show there to work. I should note that i am working with visualSVN server and that seems to use cmd files rather then bat files for it's pre-commits. However my current problem now turns towards a number of errors

Comment: cmd is quite the same as bat on a todays windows system, that has nothing to do with visualSVN. Do you have any experiences with windows shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your executable file path (`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe`), I assume you are working on a Windows machine.

The `pre-commit` file in your question looks like a Linux Bash Shell script.
Bash has a different syntax from a batch file you would use under Windows.

I suggest you use a `pre-commit.tmpl` file made for a Windows machine.
You probably have onde of these in your `hooks` folder.
I use a Linux machine, so unfortunately I can't help you further on this search...

The `pre-commit` hook will look like this (excerpt taken from [An Introduction to Subversion Hook Scripts on Windows](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/11/10/an-introduction-to-subversion-hook-scripts-on-windows/)):

```
@echo off
:: Stops commits that don't include a log message of at least 6 characters.
@echo off

setlocal

rem Subversion sends through the repository path and transaction id
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr ...... > nul
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else exit 0

:err
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1>&2
echo Your commit has been blocked because it didn't include a log message. 1>&2
echo Do the commit again, this time with a log message that describes your changes. 1>&2
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1>&2
exit 1
```